# Source of Img should be dynamic

Tags: reactjs

how can i load an img src dynamic with React ?
I tried the following:

```
 const country = this.state.countryCode;
 <img src="https://www.countryflags.io/"+country+"/shiny/64.png"/>
```

But i got the error:

> > Parsing error: Unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten curly braces. Also, you can create the url string before and use it:

```
 const url = "https://www.countryflags.io/"+this.state.countryCode+"/shiny/64.png";
 <img src={url}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't React-specific, it's because you have the `+` in the src.

Use a string [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with back-ticks:

`` src=`https://www.countryflags.io/${country}/shiny/64.png` ``